# Java Работа с числами

Tags: java, циклы, числа

Пишу программу которая показывает четные и нечетные числа в определенном интервале, заданным пользователем. И тут наткнулся на одну проблему, выбираю интервал допустим, от 120 до 130 программа показывает только четные числа, а нечетные не показывает

```
        System.out.println("Четные числа");
        for (; a <= b; a++) {
            if (a % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(a);
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
```

До этой части работает нормально, далее идут нечетные числа и тут уже ничего не высвечивается

```
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Нечетные числа");
        for (; a <= b; a++) {
            if (a % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(a);
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
```

Можете сказать в чем проблема? И да, если не трудно.. Как сделать так чтобы четные числа показал с конца, а нечетные с начала:
вот как тут например: выбрали интервал от 10 - 30

11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29

30,28,26,24,22,20,18,16,14,12,10

Comment: Можем. 1. Когда код подходит ко второму циклу, `а` уже больше `b`. Заведите отдельную переменную для счетчика цикла: `for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) { if (i % 2...`  2. `for (int i = b; i >= a; i--) { ...`

Comment: Вооот сработало)) Напиши это в ответе) Ты был прав) И да, я сделал правку в вопросе, этим тоже помоги если знаешь :)

Comment: Не буду писать. Это так тривиально, что заслуживает максимум комментария.

Comment: ну ок, спс за ответ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем ответ на вопрос, а просто пример как можно решить такую задачку с использованием Java 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите начальную страницу: ");
    int min = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    System.out.print("Введите конечную страницу: ");
    int max = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

    if ( min <= max ) {
        System.out.println("Четные числа: " + IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).boxed()
                        .sorted((x, y) -> -1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println("Нечетные числа: " + IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max).filter(n -> n % 2 != 0).boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: можно еще `Collectors.partitioningBy` использовать, чтобы поделить на два списка за один вызов стрима.

Comment: Да сработало) Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 3):

```
            StringBuilder odd = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder even = new StringBuilder();

            for (; a <= b; a++) {
                if (a % 2 == 0) {
                    even.append(a).append(",");
                }else {
                    odd.append(a).append(",");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Четные числа");
            System.out.println(even.toString().substring(0,even.length()-1));
            System.out.println("Нечетные числа");
            System.out.println(odd.toString().substring(0,odd.length()-1));
```

Comment: Спасибо) Тоже работает)